# How do to notify the client about errors in Servlet?

Tags: java, exception, servlets

I am making an application in Servlet + ReactJS.
And the question arose - how exactly to organize the notification of the client about any errors.

I only see two options:

1. In the service layer, catch exceptions (which are thrown manually in the code or inside the
   libraries used) and then return the message and the operation result code to the servlet

For example:

Servlet:

```
  @WebServlet("/")
    public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
        SomeSerivce service= new SomeSerivce();
        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
            Message msg=service.someDo(req.getParameter("test"));
            resp.setStatus(msg.getCode());
            PrintWriter printWriter = resp.getWriter();
            printWriter.write(msg.getText());
        }
    }
```

Some service that checks the type of the get-request parameter

```
public class SomeSerivce {
    public Message someDo(String param){
        Message msg = new Message();
        try {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(param);
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
            msg.setCode(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            msg.setText("some text");
            return  msg;
        }catch (Exception e){
            msg.setCode(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            msg.setText("some text");
            return  msg;
        }
        msg.setCode(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        msg.setText("some text");
        return msg;
    }
}



 public  class Message{
        private int code;
        private String text;
        .........
    }
```

2. Don't catch any exceptions and just create separate servlets that will be called when certain
   exceptions are thrown.

For example:

in web.xml

> ```
>  <error-page>
>         <exception-type>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException</exception-type>
>         <location>/AppExceptionHandler</location>
>     </error-page>
> ```

And create a servlet for the path  /AppExceptionHandler

```
@WebServlet("/AppExceptionHandler")
public class AppExceptionHandler extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
         response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
        printWriter.write("Some text");
        printWriter.close();
    }
    
}
```

Which option is better?

Comment: Neither. It's an information leak to an attacker. Just let the servlet container return HTTP 500 and let the server guys check the logs to see what it meant. It's none of the client's business.

Comment: And you should certainly not write an error-handling servlet. Error paths and pages must be as simple as possible. Consider what happens when you get an error in your error-handling servlet.

Answer (score -1):

Option 1. is better but it can be improved.
Remember that if your service is exposed to the Internet anyone can send HTTP requests to it, that's why you don't want to disclose the inner workings of your application. You should catch the exceptions that are thrown inside your service method and if any are thrown set a generic error status like 500 and log the details in a file.

This is an example

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    Message msg = null;
    try {
        msg = service.someDo(req.getParameter("test"));
        PrintWriter printWriter = resp.getWriter();
        printWriter.write(msg.getText());
    } catch (ExceptionType e) {
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        logger.error("Some message", e);
    }
}
```

In the frontend fire the HTTP request, read the HTTP response status and show your business page if it's 200 otherwise just show an error page.

Option 2. is not good because it creates a redirection and you would have to set-up your HTTP client to follow redirects.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Another bizarre robo-message. There is no question of 'correct' when the OP has asked 'which is better'. But it is necessary to provide a *reason* why you consider this better. He didn't just ask which you would do.